# Linux. intel cpu turbo boost

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, turbo-boost, ivy-bridge

I've just installed Deepin OS 15.5 on my laptop with i5 3360m CPU. Seems CPU is running at base core speeds 2.8ghz on max load. So my question how can I enable turbo boost? I don't care about power usage, I just want to use higher speed as I sometimes play games on steam.Thank for help

Comment: You can enable turbo boost, by enabling it, within the firmware settings.

Comment: Okay. And where is firmware settings located?

Comment: I have not taken the chance to memorize the interface of every UEFI firmware on the market.  First verify your CPU supports Intel Turbo Boost, second find the option in your firmware, it's not a feature of every firmware.  If you cannot find the option then it cannot be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've installed i7z and turbo boost is showing as working with the highest speed of CPU available, but other utilities are showing CPU max clock speed incorrectly.

Comment: What exactly did you install?  Edit your question

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling